# What is the difference between enthalpy of reaction and standard enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

What is the difference between enthalpy of reaction ($\Delta H$) and standard enthalpy ($\Delta H^\circ$)? I was told that the standard enthalpy of reaction is the change in heat when **one mole of matter** is transformed. I don't quite get what this one mole refers to in a chemical equation.

For example, I came across this equation in my textbook: $$\ce{N2 + O2 -> 2 NO \tag{ΔH = +181kJ/mol}}$$

Does the $\Delta H$ here mean the amount of energy absorbed during the formation of 1 mole of $\ce{NO}$? But since 2 moles of $\ce{NO}$ are produced, shouldn't it be $181\times 2 = 362$?

Comment: Be sure to take this [tour] to know about the community. Also use [MathJax](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) to format questions and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the standard enthalpy of reaction ($\Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ$) is the enthalpy change that occurs in a system when matter is transformed by a given chemical reaction, when all reactants and products are in their [standard states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_state). The only condition is that the participants have to be in their **standard states, ie. usually at 1 bar pressure.**

On the other hand, **enthalpy of reaction** ($\Delta_\mathrm{r}H$) is amount of energy absorbed or released at any condition. Considering your example, 
$$ \ce{N2 + O2 -> 2NO} \qquad \tag{$H = \pu{+181kJ}$}$$ 
Here, $\Delta$H represents the amount of heat absorbed in the formation of 2 moles of $\ce{NO}$. For the formation of **one mole** of a substance from constituent elements, it is called **enthalpy of formation**($\Delta_\mathrm{f}H$)and if in standard states, **standard enthalpy of formation**.
$$ \ce{ 1/2 N2 + 1/2 O2 -> NO} \tag{$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H$}$$
As we can see, $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H$ = $\frac{1}{2}\Delta H$. Hence it should be $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H$= +90.5 kJ/mol.

**Note**: Unit of enthalpy is that of energy but unit of enthalpy for a reaction is of energy per unit mass or amount.

Comment: It would be worth saying that the units for entalpy are just $\text{kJ}$, whereas those of enthalpy of formation are $\pu{kJ mol^-1}$

Comment: Also, standard conditions also include $\pu{298 K}$.

Comment: No there is no condition on temperature as per IUPAC but commonly known is 298K. @ralk912 Refer [standard states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_state)

Comment: Do you have a link for that?

Comment: I gave one in my answer as well as comment. Will update regarding units @ralk912

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the IUPAC would decide to do that instead of just fixing a value. In any case, then the temperature should be given when speaking of standard states I think.

Comment: Yes, it is not very intuitive. But I was taught like that.

Comment: The IUPAC has proven themselves they're not usually intuitive. You were taught right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74549/discussion-between-mollycool-and-ralk912).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm also wondering what the units are for standard enthalpy of reaction. So far I've seen kJ and kJ/mol. Can they be used interchangeably? Does the **/mol** part add anything?

Comment: Mol part indicates the enthalpy change per mol of the reaction. (If that makes sense) @chemquestion Unit for standard enthalpy change of a reaction is kJ/mol.(usual) Although we can use any combination of energy/mass or amount like kcal/mol